# What attributes does Pandora look for in a song?

Tags: pandora

Is there any way to see all of the song attributes a song has? I know it sometimes shows you several of them when it describes why a song is being played, but I'm looking for an exhaustive list.

If not, is there any way to see a list of all the criteria that they look for and rate in a song? Again, I'm looking for an all-inclusive list.

Answer (score 1):

The full list is not available because that's part of their Music Genome service offer (have to license it).

You can see a long (but not full) list of a song's attribute if you go the song's page. You can get there either from your own profile page or by navigating around. See for example: [Tainted Love](http://www.pandora.com/music/song/soft+cell/tainted+love) that lists 13 attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia has a [rather extensive list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Music_Genome_Project_attributes) of the attributes.

Pandora has a [Musical Terms Glossary](http://blog.pandora.com/mt/mt-search.cgi?IncludeBlogs=25&tag=Musical%20Terms%20Glossary&limit=20) which explains same of the attributes.

Comment: Both links are dead as of 6 Dec 2014.